# Get id of my row table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get `id` of tr my `tr` . 
what's wrong with my jquery syntax, is adding jquery to onclick function is the problem.
here is a snipet of my code, it says it's undefinned.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDIV1" style="display: inline">
 <form action="/banque" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="personForm" data-tiers-url="/ajax/load-cities/"><input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="hb4WLeqHCHVS5uanq8C0hQUhKoB8WFye3kvFLJvyUraLGn2dv3NEslm1AamSosdf">  

 <table align="center"> <!-- banque_rib <div class="row" style="padding-left:  24%; padding-top: 3%"></div> -->
  <tbody><tr> 
   
   <td><select name="banque_name" placeholder="N Facture" class="form-control" required="" id="id_banque_name">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="Attijari">Attijari</option>

  <option value="SGMB">SGMB</option>

  <option value="Ts part">Ts part</option>

</select> </td>
    
   
    <td width="2%"></td>
   <td><select name="banque_rib" placeholder="N Facture" class="form-control" required="" id="id_banque_rib">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="2142">2142</option>

  <option value="-23525">-23525</option>

  <option value="892375">892375</option>

  <option value="23">23</option>

</select> </td>
    
   
    <td width="2%"></td>
   <td><span><button class="btn btn-success form-control" id="myBtn"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></span></td>
   <td width="10%"></td>
   <td><input id="uploadFile" placeholder="Choose File" class="form-control" disabled="disabled"></td>
   <td><div class="btn btn-primary" id="divInput"><span>importer</span>
    <input type="file" name="myfile" style=" position: absolute;top: 0;right: 0;margin: 0; padding: 0;font-size: 20px;cursor: pointer;opacity: 0;filter: alpha(opacity=0);" id="uploadBtn" required="">
   </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr></tr>
   
 </tbody></table>
   <input type="hidden" id="num" name="numpiece" value="1">
      
 



<br> 

<!-- Formulaire d'ajout des liiigneee <td width="10%" colspan="2">Importer la piece Justificatif</td> -->
<p>form-0-row</p><table style="border-collapse: separate;border-spacing: 15px;" id="id_forms_table">
   
   <tbody><tr><td width="5%">N P</td><td width="8%">Date d'operation</td><td width="25%">Désignation</td><td width="10%">Type tiers</td><td width="10%">Tiers</td><td width="10%">Référence de Facture</td><td width="10%">Montant debit </td><td width="10%">Montant crédit</td></tr>
    
    <tr style="border:1px solid black;" id="form-0-row" class="dynamic-form">
     
      <td><div class="col-xs-1"><b><p name="np1">1</p></b></div></td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" name="form-0-dateOperation" value="2018-04-12" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-dateOperation">
    
   </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="form-0-designation" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-designation">
   </td>
   <td>
    <select name="form-0-typeTiers" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-typeTiers">
  <option value="__">__</option>

  <option value="Client">Client</option>

  <option value="Fournisseur">Fournisseur</option>

  <option value="CNSS">CNSS</option>

  <option value="Etat">Etat</option>

  <option value="Personnels">Personnels</option>

</select>
   </td>
   <td>
    <select name="form-0-tiers" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-tiers">
  <option value="CFF">CFF</option>

  <option value="rgg">rgg</option>

  <option value="zrfkgf">zrfkgf</option>

  <option value="Ts part">Ts part</option>

  <option value="ACAM">ACAM</option>

  <option value="Ts partPP">Ts partPP</option>

  <option value="ACM">ACM</option>

  <option value="egz">egz</option>

  <option value="rer">rer</option>

  <option value="ACM">ACM</option>

  <option value="ACM">ACM</option>

  <option value="CNSS">CNSS</option>

  <option value="IS">IS</option>

  <option value="IR">IR</option>

  <option value="TVA">TVA</option>

  <option value="patente">patente</option>

  <option value="Salaires">Salaires</option>

  <option value="primes">primes</option>

</select>
   </td>
   <td><select name="form-0-numfacture" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-numfacture">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="1">facture object</option>

  <option value="2">facture object</option>

  <option value="3">facture object</option>

  <option value="4">facture object</option>

</select>
   </td>
   <td><input type="number" name="form-0-montantdeb" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-montantdeb"></td>
   <td><input type="number" name="form-0-montantcred" class="form-control" id="id_form-0-montantcred"></td>
   
 </tr>

<tr>
               
            </tr>
</tbody></table>
<input type="hidden" name="form-TOTAL_FORMS" value="1" id="id_form-TOTAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="form-INITIAL_FORMS" value="0" id="id_form-INITIAL_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="form-MIN_NUM_FORMS" value="0" id="id_form-MIN_NUM_FORMS"><input type="hidden" name="form-MAX_NUM_FORMS" value="1000" id="id_form-MAX_NUM_FORMS">

 <!-- BUTTONS <td colspan="4"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="add-row">add property</a></td> -->
 <input type="submit" name="annuler" value="Annuler" class="btn btn-danger" style="float:right ;margin: 5px; margin-right: 35px">
 <button value="" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right;margin: 5px;" onclick="">enregistrer</button>    

</form>

<input type="submit" name="ajoutligne" value="Ajouter une ligne" class="btn btn-primary" id="add-row" style="background-color: #8C1944; border-color: #8C1944; float:right;margin: 5px;" onclick="test()">
 
</div>
<script>function test(){
var dat = $("#id_forms_table tr").attr('id')
alert(dat);
}</script>
```

Any help please I dont see what the problem is .

Comment: That should be fine. But it depends on where you are using it. Do you wanna show a [mcve]? Did you include jQuery in your code? Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Did you include you jquery lib?

Comment: Its working fine for me?i is there any error you got?

Comment: I made you a snippet. It works. Did you wrap the jQuery in a load event? Like `$(function() { var dat = $("#id_forms_table tr").attr('id');
alert(dat); });`

Comment: Better use ";" at the end of first code row but seems like it's not the problem. Do you add "Jquery" to your project correctly?

Comment: my jquery is included. one thing I forgot to mention is that this jquery is called in an on click function.

Comment: @Elroum Doesn't matter if its' called in click event as it references only global selectors.

Comment: Please update the snippet I made to show the problem you have

Comment: okey I'll do so .

Comment: @Elroum Check your question. It works well.

Comment: This is what I wanted to say. It works here; but in my code it doesnt , so I guess there is another problem in my code

Answer (score 1):

Include jQuery in your head.

Also if you don't call the function in a load event or after the object exists it will not going to execute your alert.

When you included jQuery library try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var dat=$("#id_forms_table tr").attr('id')
        alert(dat);
});
```

Also when you try to have more `tr` select the right one for the specific id

```
var dat = $("#id_forms_table tr:nth-child(2)").attr('id')
```

Comment: Are you sure that the OP hasn't included jQuery?

Comment: OPs code is ONLY working fine if OP does what is suggested above. Why downvote?

Comment: I think there is no need to have `$( document ).ready()` its working fine without it

Comment: in the code snippet it works, but in my code it doenst. there should be another problem in my code.

Comment: @Elroum please place your updated code, including jQuery library and where function is placed

Comment: I edited my code with all the div that contains my Table. and it's giving in the snippet now the problem 'undefined'

Comment: @Elroum it is because you have more `tr` in your table and you are requesting the first `id` of the table. Change this line `var dat=$("#id_forms_table tr").attr('id')` to this line `var dat = $("#id_forms_table tr:nth-child(2)").attr('id')` should work now

Comment: yes it works . thank you so much. please transform your comment to an ansewer